# Entity Framework deletes valid content without permission in a non-deterministic way?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm having troubles with storing data to the database with EF. Usually all CRUD operations works fine for the rest of the program, but recently I have noticed, that in case of m:n relationship, the tricky part comes.

I'm using EF4.1 with code first approach. The interesting parts of my classes look as follows:

```
public class Publication : IItem, IDataErrorInfo {

     ...

    [InverseProperty("Publications")]
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups{ get; set; }
}

public class Group : IItem, IDataErrorInfo {

     ...

    [InverseProperty("Groups")]
    public virtual ICollection<Publication> Groups{ get; set; }
}
```

The database is created as follows:

```
    public PublicationsDB() : base("PublicationDB") {
        this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
    }

    public DbSet<Publication> Publications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Software> Softwares { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Group{ get; set; }
```

The intention is to create m:n relationship between Publications and Groups.

When lately I'm  importing data from XML, everything works great. Either Publications and Groups have their ICollection stored after the SaveChanges() is called. In the same method a few lines below I'm getting data from database (just for check) and again both entities have their ICollection filled.

**And here comes the trouble:**

When executing a different function for data manipulation, I dig data out of the database   and:

- The collection of Publications is fine, ale of the entities have proper `ICollection<Group>` filled from xml
- But the collection of Groups is quite messed up. Most of them have `ICollection<Publication>` set to null.

What the problem might be? Such behavior is really weird to me. Last but not least the deletion of Collections from `DBSet<Groups>` is not deterministic. I mean if we considere Group A and Group B, than in one run of the program `A.ICollection = null and B.ICollection.Count =1 (which is by the way wrong)` whereas in other run is different, i.e. `A.ICollection = null and B.ICollection = null (which is also wrong)`

Any ideas?

Messed model when building code first DB? framework error or weird internal framework optimization? or am I just an arsehole? :)

I was also thinking of changing the relationship by placing a new entity inside. 
i.e to shift `Publication (m):(n) Group` to something like `Publication (m):(1) NewEntityRelation (n):1 Group`, but I would rather prefer a different solution if there is such.

Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm mistaken, the InverseProperty attribute  helps EF pair up one side of a relationship with the other side, but it doesn't tell EF anything about what kind of relationship it is. I'm assuming that when you say you want to create an "m:n" relationship what you mean is "many to many", and I've found EF doesn't always figure it out correctly. I've made it a habit to specify the mapping manually for many-to-many relations by overriding the OnModelCreating method. The following is a sample code snippet:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(a => a.Roles)
            .WithMany(r => r.Users)
            .Map(config =>
            {
                config.ToTable("UserRoles");
                config.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                config.MapRightKey("RoleId");
            });
    }
```

The above snippet is taken from a project of mine where it's used to define a many-to-many relation between users and their roles in the system. This way EF doesn't get "confused" about what kind of relationship, the name of the intermediary table in the database, or the keys used to map the one side to the other. I'm not sure why you're seeing the problems on only one side of the relation, but I'd be willing to bet it's because EF hasn't been able to quite figure out what you're trying to do.